# Como retornar o ultimo registro de cada venda

Tags: sql, oracle

Como retornar o ultimo registro de cada venda considerando a max(data)?

```
+---------+--------------------+---------------+
|venda    |Data                |id             |
+---------+--------------------+---------------|
|0000001  |2021-01-10 12:04:45 |0000000000001  |
|0000001  |2021-01-10 12:14:20 |0000000000002  |
|0000002  |2021-01-12 12:20:59 |0000000000003  |
|0000002  |2021-01-12 12:21:20 |0000000000004  |
|0000003  |2021-01-12 12:30:23 |0000000000005  |
|0000004  |2021-01-13 12:21:20 |0000000000006  |
|0000004  |2021-01-14 12:21:20 |0000000000007  |
|0000004  |2013-02-15 12:20:59 |0000000000008  |
+---------+--------------------+---------------+

SELECT
    *
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    DATA =(
        SELECT
            MAX( DATA )
        FROM
            foo
    )
```

esse select que fiz retorna só a ultima linha de tudo e deveria retornar:

```
+---------+--------------------+---------------+
|venda    |Data                |id             |
+---------+--------------------+---------------|
|0000001  |2021-01-10 12:14:20 |0000000000002  |
|0000002  |2021-01-12 12:21:20 |0000000000004  |
|0000003  |2021-01-12 12:30:23 |0000000000005  |
|0000004  |2013-02-15 12:20:59 |0000000000008  |
+---------+--------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o seguinte:

```
SELECT venda, max(data) from foo group by venda;
```

Comment: show de bola man, era isso mesmo. O segredo estava no group by que não prestei atenção. Obrigado, ajudou um jovem a adquirir um novo conhecimento. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: De nada @HugoLeonardo, boa sorte

Comment: Eu acrescentaria order by venda na query acima para ordenar

Comment: @PauloRogerio eu também se isso fosse pedido, o ORDER BY é desnessário e custoso, só deve usar se precisar.

Comment: O que diz dizer é que a consulta  acima retornaria o que vc precisava, se colocasse um ORDER BY. Mas sei que é custoso, Mas resolveria

Comment: @PauloRogerio só não percebo porque é que isso é um requisito, olhando outravez para a pergunta isso não é preciso. A consulta da minha resposta já vai retornar o último registo de cada venda, nada aqui menciona a ordem que deve estar no output.